# Basis for row space

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Is it correct to say that once you find a basis for the row space of a matrix $A$, then all the rows in that matrix can be written as a linear combination of the basis vectors?

Thanks.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: This is in the definition of a basis in vector space. It can be added, the linear combination is unique.